# Origins and usage of '襨'

Tags: characters

I remember once reading about a Chinese character in Unicode that noone knew its meaning and purpose, and after some googling, I found **襨**. Aside from basic character databases like Wiktionary or Unihan, I wasn't able to find any sources about this character in English.

So, does this character have a meaning? How was this character introduced in Unicode? Are there other such "mysterious" characters?

Answer (score 7):

[襨 U+8968](http://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=gb&char=%E8%A5%A8)

國語發音: dù  ㄉㄨˋ

The first entry in 原典出處:

> 《金陵秋·第四章鄂變》：  計革人既潛漢口，而武昌中**襨伏**必多。

襨伏 means 埋伏. Thus, I guess 襨 means something related to 埋 (bury, secrete, conceal)。